# Как разбить одномерный массив на многомерный по определенному слову?

Tags: javascript, массивы

Помогите заполнить многомерный массив.

Импортируется таблица в инпут, полученную строку разбил по словам и положил в ячеку одномерного массива

```
addMoreProduct(string) {
    this.allProduct.push(string.split('\t'));
    this.string = '';
  }
```

А как разбить полученный массив на многомерный по определенному слову?

**Пример:**

В инпут вводится строка:

```
'Word 1 2 3 4 5 6 Word 1 2 3 4 5 6'
```

Эта строка получена копированием из таблицы excel

Мой код разбивает строку на массив

```
[Word, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, Word, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6]
```

а надо получить двумерный массив

```
[[Word, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6] [Word, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6]]
```

Comment: Не совсем понятно задание, было бы неплохо, если бы вы привели пример входных данных и данные, которые надо получить на выходе

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Вариант с пробелами

```js
let str = 'Word 1 2 3 4 5 6 Word 7 8 9 10 11 12';
let result = [];

var addMoreProduct = function(string) {
  let arr = string.split(' ');
  let subarr = [];
  for (let i = 0; i <= arr.length; i++) {
    if (arr[i] == 'Word' && subarr.length > 0 || (i == arr.length && subarr.length > 0)) {
      result.push(subarr);
      subarr = [];
    }
    subarr.push(arr[i]);
  }
  return (result)
}

console.log(addMoreProduct(str));
```

Вариант с табуляциями

```js
let str = 'Word 1 2 3 4 5 6 Word 7 8 9 10 11 12'
let result = [];

var addMoreProduct = function(string) {
  let arr = string.split('\t');
  let subarr = [];
  for (let i = 0; i <= arr.length; i++) {
    if (arr[i] == 'Word' && subarr.length > 0 || (i == arr.length && subarr.length > 0)) {
      result.push(subarr);
      subarr = [];
    }
    subarr.push(arr[i]);
  }
  return (result)
}

console.log(addMoreProduct(str));
```

Comment: Отличный ответ! Только в вопросе копируют с Excel и там наверное не пробелы будут, а табуляция.

Comment: Скорее всего так и есть, тогда ничего не помешает заменить пробел на `\t`, пожалуй так и сделаю. Спасибо за замечание.

Comment: Спасибо большое, очень помогли!

Answer (score 2):

Ответ не претендует на самый быстрый или на самый универсальный.

Разбиваем сначала по ключевому слову, затем по символу табуляции.

```js
var array = 'Word 1 2 3 4 5 6 7 Word 1 2 3 4 5 76'
  .split(/\s?Word\s?/)
  .filter(f => f !== "")
  .map(m => m.split('\t'));
console.log(array);
```

Comment: У вас немного не по заданию получается, у вас в массивах отсутствует слово `word`.

Comment: @SergeyGlazirin да, так и есть. Вы абсолютно правы. Оставлю это на суд спрашивающего))

Comment: Вы решили задачу на строке, а у меня массив. split не получится сделать. Но спасибо за помощь! =)

Comment: @Bloodleon извините, где написано, что у вас массив? У вас написано *В инпут вводится строка*. И у меня строка. Где массив то?))

Comment: @Stepan Kasyanenko, собственно название темы, и в примере сказано что я получил массив, а надо двумерный массив)

Comment: @Bloodleon Смотрите, надо сделать вам два шага. Первый: разбить  строчку на массив строчек. Второй: разбить массив строчек на вложенные массивы. Вы смогли сделать шаг Первый, вы просите помочь сделать шаг Второй. Я сделал в ответе Первый и Второй шаг. В чем проблма?))

Answer (score 0):

Коротенькое решение:

```
var line = 'Word 1 2 3 4 5 6 Word 1 2 3 4 5 6';
var result = [];
line.replace(/(Word[\s\d]+)(?=\sWord)/g, '$1,')
.split(',')
.forEach(function(el) { 
result.push(el.split(' '));
});
```

Comment: А если будет вот такая входная строка `Word 1,2 2 3 4 5 6 Word 1 2 3 4 5 6`? Мне кажется, в таком случае у вас будет не совсем верный результат.

Comment: Не проблема: replace(/(Word[,\s\d]+)(?=\sWord)/g, '$1;'), split(';') и el.split(/[,\s]/)

Comment: А если будет `Word 1;2 2 3 4 5 6 Word 1 2 3 4 5 6,7`? Я хочу сказать, что слова разбиваются по пробельным символам, а не по запятым, точкой с запятой и прочим знакам))

Comment: Код основан на регулярном выражении, поэтому не проблема и под это условие подправить;).

Comment: Все с вами понятно)))

Comment: Это типо спасибо? Тогда, не за что)

Comment: Я не задавал вопрос, если что. Я такой же отвечающий, как и вы) Просто хотел посоветовать вам, указать на то, что в определенных ситуациях ваш код будет работать не верно. Хотел помочь)